# Execute sql stored procedure by passing parameters as a query

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I tried many time to pass query as parameter to the execute a `stored procedure`. But it is giving compile time error everytime. Below is my `query`

```
exec IAM_INSERT_ASSET (select top 1 ItemID from MIR_ItemMaster order by ItemID desc),1662
```

There are two parameters, out of which first is dynamic by the query and second is hard coded. `Obviously I can do this by keeping query in variable and passing variable.` But I do not want to declare variable and pass query directly to the procedure. How can this be achieved. Any help?

Comment: What are the datatypes of the stored procedure? The same as ItemID? Use a variable. running the procedure is one statement so it can't have another statement in it.

Comment: Datatype is same as of parameter

Comment: Why are you not using variable? I think this is the way to pass dynamic parameters.

Comment: @kitty : Yes of course, but there are number of procedures to which there are all dynamic parameters. So I thought it will be good to pass queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I haven't got access to SQL Server right now, so this may not work.

Secondly, I don't understand why you don't want to use a variable - it's by far the simplest solution. If you're building your stored procedures to be too clever - e.g. have IAM_INSERT_ASSET behave differently depending on the first parameter's values, I'd recommend you reconsider that. Stored procedures are hard to test, hard to debug, and hard to understand from an architectural point of view, so you often end up breaking a stored procedure through an apparently unrelated change (e.g. adding a column to a table).

Finally, if you really want to do this, you can use [dynamic SQL](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-dynamic-sql-in-stored-procedures). If you change the first parameter to be a varchar, and then use `sp_executeSQL` to execute the contents of that varchar, you can pass in whatever you want. Caveat - I don't know if this works, can't try it. Other caveat - this may make your system brittle and fail in exciting ways.

Answer (score 1):

All<sup>1</sup> that you can supply in an `EXEC` statement are literal *values* or variables. Here's the documented syntax for [`EXEC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx):

```
[ { EXEC | EXECUTE } ]
    { 
      [ @return_status = ]
      { module_name [ ;number ] | @module_name_var } 
        [ [ @parameter = ] { value 
                           | @variable [ OUTPUT ] 
                           | [ DEFAULT ] 
                           }
        ]
      [ ,...n ]
      [ WITH <execute_option> [ ,...n ] ]
    }
[;]
```

That's it. So you'll have to go the variable route.

---

<sup>1</sup> You can also use a *few* of the built in functions, like `@@IDENTITY`, which used to be a "global variable", but it's very much the exception rather than the rule.

Answer (score 1):

@eraj
I get your basic query.
However, I don't think it can be done exactly the way you want to, i.e. passing the query as a parameter.
This can be done in two ways I feel.

1) Write a cursor with this SELECT and Execute the SP from within the cursor.

```
DECLARE @p1 varchar(800);
DECLARE @p2 varchar(800);
DECLARE @p3 varchar(800);

DECLARE SP_Cursor CURSOR
    FOR SELECT p1,p2,p3
        FROM ..

OPEN SP_Cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM SP_Cursor INTO @p1, @p2, @p3;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)  
BEGIN  
    EXEC SP_Name @p1,@p2,@p3;  
    FETCH NEXT FROM SP_Cursor INTO @p1, @p2, @p3;  
END  

CLOSE SP_Cursor;

DEALLOCATE SP_Cursor;
```

As I said, this would be slow as hell since if your query returns 1000 rows, the SP would execute 1000 times connecting to the DB every time.
You can improve the performance somewhat by putting the data set into a #temp_table and looping through a WHILE loop. It would at least cut out on connecting to the DB each time.

2) The second option is to build the execution statement itself through a SELECT query.

```
declare @execstatementsbatch nvarchar(max)
select @execstatementsbatch = ''

SELECT @execstatementsbatch = @execstatementsbatch   + 'EXEC SP_Name' + p1 +  ', '  + p2 +  ', '  + p3 + '; ' 
FROM..
<some conditions>

exec(@execstatementsbatch)
```

But mind you, both are not very good for performance in case you're working with huge amount of data.

---

Answer (score 0):

Why not define the first parameter as varchar and pass the query as a string?
It would basically look like,

```
exec IAM_INSERT_ASSET 'select top 1 ItemID from MIR_ItemMaster order by ItemID desc',1662
```

Comment: I have all parameters dynamic. It will be more cumbersome job change datatype of input parameters of every procedure

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work?

```
declare @docnumber2 char(21) -- or whatever the field is varchar,int,etc.
set @docnumber2 = (select top 1 docnumber from invoices order by doc_timestamp)
exec udsp_blahblah @docnumber2
```